# Is the Android Fragment a Linux process?

Tags: android, linux, android-fragments, process

The question is very simple: is the Android Fragment a linux process different from the Activity one?

Comment: When you say "consider", do you mean **is it** a seperate process, or do you want to do something specific with it that means it needs to **act** like a seperate process?

Comment: I mean is it a separate process, now I correct the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Fragments are simple objects. Their code is not run by separate processes.

Comment: But they have their life cycle!

Comment: @Maghio: The existence of methods named "lifecycle methods" has nothing to do whether the Java object offering those methods runs on one process versus another process.

Comment: Ok so, generally speaking, fragments run into the linux process wich contains the Activity?

Comment: @Maghio: Generally speaking, everything in an Android app runs in one process. Few apps use more than one process, and IMHO many of those that do are poorly written.

Comment: I don't think so. An android app is made by services too wich are linux processes infact with the ps comand you can see services.

Comment: @Budius I think services are in different processes if you need they run while the activity is destroyed

Comment: @Maghio: "services too wich are linux processes infact" -- no, services are not Linux processes. Services can be configured to run on a separate process, via the `android:process` attribute in the manifest. By default, they run on the main process for the app. You may wish to read [the documentation on processes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) (e.g., "By default, all components of the same application run in the same process"). There is no means of running a fragment, or an `Integer`, or a `HashMap`, on its own process in Android.

Comment: @Budius thanks man, you were very accurate.
CommonsWare i was speaking about the case of services configured to run on separate processes. Thanks you too